# In PHP PDO, how can I bind named parameters of a prepared statement without knowing their names?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to write a helper query function to return a resultset to the caller, but when the caller provides a prepared statement using named params, I am not sure how to bind them in a function.

```
function queryDB(string $query, array $param=null) {
  
  global $dbh; //reference the db handle declared in init.php 

  if (isset($param)) { //query params provided, so a prepared statement
    
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    for($i = 1; $i <= count($param);$i++) { //bind the parameters 1-by-1
      $stmt->bindParam($i, $param[$i]); //
    }
    $stmt->execute();

  } else { //a straight sql query, not a prepared statement

    $stmt = $dbh->query($query);   

  }
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
  return $result;
}
```

If I call `queryDB($query, [$name, $age])` with an unnamed-param prepared statement such as `$query = INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES(?, ?)` and `$name = "trump"; $age = 18`, that code should work.

But there can be times when I (or someone else) will call with a named-param prepared statement such as `$query = INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES(:name, :age)` and `$name = "trump"; $age = 18`. The existing bindParam(i, $value) shouldn't work but then the function wouldn't know those `:name, :age, :whatever` named parameters. How should I write the `bindParam(param, value)` to accommodate both named and unnamed prepared statements? assuming params will be provided in the matched order even when named.

Comment: Just pass `$param` to the `execute` no need for that `bindparam`.

Comment: `foreach ($param as $key => $value) $stmt->bindParam($key, $value);`… Then pass `$param` as either numerically index array or associative array…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's absolutely no reason to use `bindParam`.

If your SQL has named placeholders then your array must be associative. You need to call it like this:

```
queryDB($query, ['name' => $name, 'age' => $age]);
```

You could then loop with `foreach($params as $key => $value)` and use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`, but, as I said, there's absolutely no reason to use it.

Instead, pass the array to `execute`.

```
function queryDB(PDO $dbh, string $query, ?array $param = null)
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($param);
    return $stmt;
}
```

P.S. You can even remove the `if` statement and the call to `query`. This method does the same thing as `prepare` and `execute`. There's no reason to have a special case like this in your code.

Also, this function will become much more flexible if if would return just $stmt. This way you can use it for DML queries as well and also use many other fetch modes supported by PDO other than simple fetchAll(), i.e. `queryDB($dbh, $query, $param)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);`

Comment: I see your code works and much more terse, but I prefer verbosity to increase clarity (for myself) and I find bindParam() more clear (again for me).

Comment: @Manachi What does this have to do with this answer?